# Change between numbers system

Tags: arraylist, numbers

I try to change big numbers between number systems. Bin to Dec, from Dec to Oct, etc. I try to do it on int/long but there is to small range.

```
public static String naSystem(String liczba,int system){
    int dec = 0;
    for (int a=0, b=liczba.length()-1; a<liczba.length(); a++, b--) {
        String n = liczba.substring(a, a+1);
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\d");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(n);
        if (!matcher.matches()) {
            dec += (((int)liczba.charAt(a) - 55) * Math.pow(system, b));
        } else {
            dec += (Integer.parseInt(n) * Math.pow(system, b));
        }
    }
    return String.valueOf(dec);
}
```

I think the only way is to use ArrayList but I do not know how to do it